# Properly comparing Arm machine code to assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, machine-code

I am getting used to looking at the assembly output on Arm, and thought it'd be fun to take a peek at the machine code since I have the reference and can easily see it all in front of me. However, I am finding that it doesn't match what I expected to see. This tells me that I am a little mistaken somewhere. Maybe someone can help me out. Here is my asm:

```
    .arch armv8-m.main
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 6
    .eabi_attribute 34, 1
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "arm_test.c"
    .text
    .align  1
    .global main
    .syntax unified
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   main, %function
main:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    push    {r7}
    sub sp, sp, #12
    add r7, sp, #0
    movs    r3, #2
    str r3, [r7, #4]
    ldr r3, [r7, #4]
    adds    r3, r3, #13
    str r3, [r7]
    movs    r3, #0
    mov r0, r3
    adds    r7, r7, #12
    mov sp, r7
    @ sp needed
    pop {r7}
    bx  lr
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 9-2020-q2-update) 9.3.1 20200408 (release)"
```

and here is the beginning of my hex output (from objcopy):

```
:0C800000F8B500BFF8BC08BC9E467047F5
:10800C0008B50021044600F0F5F8044B1868C36B62
:10801C0003B19847204600F0C7F900BFC4830000A5
:10802C00024B13B1024800F047B970470000000042
:10803C00D182000010B5054C237833B9044B13B131
:10804C00044800E000BF0123237010BD1488010018
:10805C0000000000D083000008B5034B1BB103499E
:10806C00034800E000BF08BD0000000018880100B4
```

Now since arm defaults to little-endian, I expected the first byte (0x47) to be a PUSH command. But 0x47 = 0b01000111 which looks like a BLX instruction to me. So fine, maybe it starts with a branch? If this is true, then since it is a 16bit instruction, the next instruction starts with 0x46 (I think?). Now 0x46 = 0b01000110 looks like a MOV (another 16bit instruction). ... But now it's already starting to feel like this doesn't correspond to the ASM... So, since I am clearly look at this incorrectly, could anyone point me to the correct place to start?

Comment: How did you create that hex? Also, you might be interested in an assembly listing e.g. `as -al` and/or a disassembly e.g. `objdump -d`

Comment: @Jester I just used `arm-eabi-none-objcopy -O ihex input.elf output.hex` to get the hex

Comment: @TrivialCase how did you get from asm to object to elf in particular from object to elf?

Comment: @old_timer The asm is from `arm-eabi-none-gcc -march=armv8-m.main -S in.c -o out.S` and the elf is just the same but no `-S` and `out.elf`. I'm guessing that this is somehow wrong based on the questions?

Comment: armv8-m implies microcontroller which means you likely dont want the stock bootstrap file and linker script that is part of this cross compiler.  That leads to where did you get this cross compiler and was it specifically built and packaged for this specific mcu or board?  If not then no that is not how you want to do it.

Comment: @old_timer I got it from the arm toolchain, which is the one I use to program Arm Cortex-M33 MCUs (STM32L5xx, Nordix nRF9160, etc).  The output works on my MCUs, so I don't think that is the problem (?)

Comment: Show the rest of your work, the arm toolchain isnt a thing arm has more than one site that hosts pre-built gnu tools for arm, which are not specific to any mcu.  And they cant possibly know what linker script you want for your mcu as stm32 and nxp, etc are going to want different ones.   You need to examine the whole thing and be in control of the whole thing.  Take a final elf as shown in my answer disassemble that as Jester and I show and just look at the beginning of the disassembly to start to see what is going on, what target, etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M33  m33 is a "mainline" armv8-m so it will support the armv7-m instructions, but if you are not careful and try this on an m23 it may fail.  You really need to be in control for bare metal...

Comment: Arm has its own toolchain, multiple in fact, ADS, then one in the middle then RVCT, then whatever they have now they own Keil now so there is that one and maybe they replaced it with an RVCT derivative and then they started producing a gnu based tool and then changed the website as to where that was stored as they continued to move it forward.  so "arm toolchain" is a big vague, the assembly language here though is gnu assembler not the other arm assembly languages (ads, rvct, kiel, ...) so this is a gnu toolchain you are talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your code as is.

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   b480        push    {r7}
   2:   b083        sub sp, #12
   4:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
   6:   2302        movs    r3, #2
   8:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
   a:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
   c:   330d        adds    r3, #13
   e:   603b        str r3, [r7, #0]
  10:   2300        movs    r3, #0
  12:   4618        mov r0, r3
  14:   370c        adds    r7, #12
  16:   46bd        mov sp, r7
  18:   bc80        pop {r7}
  1a:   4770        bx  lr
```

Your hex file smells a little fishy for an armv8-m.  lower address of 0x8000?  Likewise is this the object or the complete binary?  Hex files only make sense as a complete binary where disassembling the object is not 100% cooked, but more cooked than the assembly language itself.

```
:0C800000F8B500BFF8BC08BC9E467047F5
:10800C0008B50021044600F0F5F8044B1868C36B62
:10801C0003B19847204600F0C7F900BFC4830000A5
```

Note:

```
$(ARMGNU)-objcopy --srec-forceS3 so.elf -O srec so.srec
```

While you may have a strong religious stance on intel vs motorola.  With the S3 lines you get the full address. Bottom line is the consumer of the binary, you have to match the format the consumer uses (the mcu programming tool, etc.). When I make my own tools srec with S3 enabled is the way to go.  Many tools support elf files directly so these files are generally not needed.  Others support the raw binary image (-O binary) so again the hex formats are not needed. YMMV

Hmm, push {r7} is pretty clear there is only one b4 in your hex file and it is a checksum.

There is a bx lr in this line

```
:10802C00024B13B1024800F047B9 7047 0000000042
```

So first attempt is

```
.thumb
.inst.n 0x4B02
.inst.n 0xB113  
.inst.n 0x4802
.inst.n 0xF000
.inst.n 0xB947
.inst.n 0x4770
.inst.n 0x0000
.inst.n 0x0000
```

which gives

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (c <.text+0xc>)
   2:   b113        cbz r3, a <.text+0xa>
   4:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (10 <.text+0x10>)
   6:   f000 b947   b.w 298 <.text+0x298>
   a:   4770        bx  lr
   c:   0000        movs    r0, r0
```

since there is a b.w disassembled there no need to go further.  You have a single bx lr in yours so

Oh wait there is one in the first line as well

```
   0:   b5f8        push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   2:   bf00        nop
   4:   bcf8        pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7}
   6:   bc08        pop {r3}
   8:   469e        mov lr, r3
   a:   4770        bx  lr
```

So I do not see your (machine) code in the ihex file.

We do not see a lot of 0xEx bytes every four bytes either, so it is probably not full sized arm instructions even though the 0x8000 kinda implies this was built as a linux binary for full sized arm.

objcopy to make hex type files from the object (elf, not a linked elf)

```
S00A00006F75742E7478740F
S3150000000080B483B000AF02237B607B680D333B6016
S31100000010002318460C37BD4680BC704724
S70500000000FA

:1000000080B483B000AF02237B607B680D333B601C
:0C001000002318460C37BD4680BC70472A
:00000001FF
```

We can see the 0xb480 up front and the 0x4770 at the end.  Note that some tools do NOT byte swap the hex files you might see a 4770 rather than a 7047, nothing wrong with that just how the world is sometimes...Both the creator and the consumer of the hex file need to be in sync on this.

EDIT

Extremely minimal but this is the kind of thing you are looking to do

flash.s (vector table and bootstrap)

```
.thumb
.word 0x20001000
.word reset
.thumb_func
reset:
    bl main
    b .
```

flash.ld (linker script)

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .hello : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .world : { *(.data*) } > ted
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m23 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m23 -mthumb -c so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf > so.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --srec-forceS3 so.elf -O srec so.srec
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary so.elf so.bin
```

Examine

```
08000000 <reset-0x8>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f801   bl  800000e <main>
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <reset+0x4>

0800000e <main>:
 800000e:   b480        push    {r7}
 8000010:   b083        sub sp, #12
 8000012:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
 8000014:   2302        movs    r3, #2
 8000016:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
 8000018:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
 800001a:   330d        adds    r3, #13
 800001c:   603b        str r3, [r7, #0]
 800001e:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 8000020:   4618        mov r0, r3
 8000022:   370c        adds    r7, #12
 8000024:   46bd        mov sp, r7
 8000026:   bc80        pop {r7}
 8000028:   4770        bx  lr

(naturally you can make an ihex or whatever other format you want)

S00A0000736F2E7372656338
S31508000000001000200900000800F001F8FEE780B49F
S3150800001083B000AF02237B607B680D333B6000230F
S30F0800002018460C37BD4680BC704731
S70500000000FA

hexdump -C so.bin
00000000  00 10 00 20 09 00 00 08  00 f0 01 f8 fe e7 80 b4  |... ............|
00000010  83 b0 00 af 02 23 7b 60  7b 68 0d 33 3b 60 00 23  |.....#{`{h.3;`.#|
00000020  18 46 0c 37 bd 46 80 bc  70 47                    |.F.7.F..pG|
0000002a
```

The vector table is in the right place and looks good (handler address ORRed with 1), so it will not hang on boot.  Do not know which specific core you have I just took one so I could use -mcpu...if you pick cortex-m0 it will so far work on all of the cortex-ms, might be slower at times, but will function.  The bigger mistake is cut and pasting armv7-m stuff to an armv6-m or some armv8-ms and that will not work so also examine the disassembly to see if any armv7-m instructions are in there, that will nicely land you in a handler as well (as the vector table being wrong)

Most folks want to support .data and .bss and have them initialized which makes for a more complicated linker script and bootstrap.

EDIT2

If you want to use C semi-directly (gcc calls the assembler for you)

so.c

```
int main ( void )
{
    return(5);
}
```

almost the same, changed it to -m33 here as well.

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m33 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m33 -mthumb -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf > so.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary so.elf so.bin
```

gives

```
08000000 <reset-0x8>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f802   bl  8000010 <main>
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <reset+0x4>
    ...

08000010 <main>:
 8000010:   2005        movs    r0, #5
 8000012:   4770        bx  lr
```

The 0x08000000 is most if not all of the stm32s (some 0x00200000), 0x01000000 for the ti's I know about (msp432s and maybe the formerly luminary micros).  nxp is probably 0x00000000 if I remember right or some are.  I do not remember about nordic or the others off hand.  Just read the documentation.  Technically all should work for small binaries using 0x00000000 but for example the nucleo boards (stm32) will not let you copy the .bin file over it will error if the address is wrong.  Freescale or someone has even more rules on the copy the bin file thing.

You really need to control the bootstrap and linker script yourself even if you borrow it from someone.  The C library or hal library will also play a role and maybe that is how you are actually building stuff now that the makefiles there are using the bootstrap and linker script from the hal/cmsis/other library.  Many will for some reason make heavy linker scripts that try to solve a lot of problems for everything, bootstrap, C library if any, chip library, compiler library, etc.  Rather than lean and mean and have things just work naturally. I recommend starting minimal and then getting more complex but then you sacrifice a C library and hal/whatever libraries from the vendors.

When you get into baremetal one of the things on the list is either just use someone else's sandbox or master the tools.  Looks like you want to master the tools, and that is good, the above makes it look easy...If you do not make it complicated then it can remain easy.

Comment: thumb2 is variable length instructions and it is technically possible (I have demonstrated it at this site) to confuse objdump, but if you dont strip labels and dont try really hard the disassembly will look good.  Note that it disassembles data as well (the vector table) trying hard to disassembly everything.  Not bad at all with arm, but this problem gets pretty bad with x86 disassembly.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help, you've given me lots to play with here.

Comment: And incidentally, yes I'm trying very hard to gain mastery of the tools and the platform... progress is hard fought but very fun and rewarding.

Comment: This has been extremely helpful and instructive - can't thank you enough!

Comment: Please pay it forward.  Go answer a few questions or block traffic so an elderly person can cross the road, hold a door for someone...etc...